springboot+myabtisplus+sharding-jdbc can't use my custom algorithm, error is logic table doesn't exist
version
springboot version is 2.3.5.RELEASE
mybatis-plus 3.5.1
sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter 4.1.1
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>    
<properties>
    <mybatis-plus.version>3.5.1</mybatis-plus.version>
    <sharding-jdbc>4.1.1</sharding-jdbc>
</properties>

bootstrap.properties
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.names=ds
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.ds.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.ds.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.ds.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/XXX?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&useSSL=false
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.ds.username=xxx
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.ds.password=xxx

spring.shardingsphere.sharding.tables.geo.actual-data-nodes=ds.geo_$->{0..4}
spring.shardingsphere.sharding.tables.geo.table-strategy.standard.sharding-column=area_code

spring.shardingsphere.sharding.tables.geo.table-strategy.standard.precise-algorithm-class-name=com.xxx.xxx.basic.web.config.shardingJdbc.GeoPreciseAlgorithm
spring.shardingsphere.sharding.tables.geo.table-strategy.standard.range-algorithm-class-name=com.xxx.xxx.basic.web.config.shardingJdbc.GeoRangeAlgorithm
spring.shardingsphere.props.sql.show=true

description
one database:ds.
logic table: geo.
sharding-column: area_code
geo is divided into 4 tables:geo_0 geo_1 geo_2 geo_3.
set custom Algorithm GeoPreciseAlgorithm and GeoRangeAlgorithm
public class GeoPreciseAlgorithm implements PreciseShardingAlgorithm<String> {

public GeoPreciseAlgorithm() {
}


@Override
public String doSharding(Collection<String> availableTargetNames, PreciseShardingValue<String> shardingValue) {

    String areaCode = shardingValue.getValue();
    GridType gridType = GridType.getGridTypeByAreaCode(areaCode);
    if (ObjectUtil.isNull(gridType)) {
        throw new BizException(ResponseEnum.EXCEPTION.getCode(), "params error!");
    }
    for (String availableTargetName : availableTargetNames) {
        String tableSuffix = availableTargetName.substring(availableTargetName.lastIndexOf("_"));
        if (Convert.toStr(gridType.getValue()).equals(tableSuffix)) {
            return availableTargetName;
        }
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

}
public class GeoRangeAlgorithm implements RangeShardingAlgorithm<String> {

public GeoRangeAlgorithm() {
}

@Override
public Collection<String> doSharding(Collection<String> availableTargetNames, RangeShardingValue<String> shardingValue) {

    Range<String> range = shardingValue.getValueRange();
    Integer leftBoundaryValue = Convert.toInt(range.lowerEndpoint());
    Integer rightBoundaryValue = Convert.toInt(range.upperEndpoint());

    List<String> resultCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String availableTargetName : availableTargetNames) {
        Integer point = Convert.toInt(availableTargetName.substring(availableTargetName.lastIndexOf("_")));
        if (leftBoundaryValue.compareTo(point) > 0 || rightBoundaryValue.compareTo(point) < 0) {
            continue;
        }
        resultCollection.add(availableTargetName);
    }
    if (CollectionUtil.isEmpty(resultCollection)) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    return resultCollection;
}

}
data picture
table picture
error
error picture
I don't know why the data can be save into logic table?
my custom Algorithm are no use
please give an answer thanks
1.alter properties
2.alter mybatis-plus configuration
